How to add a column to a pedigree table using JavaScript


<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8">Ancestor 1</td>
    <td rowspan="4">Ancestor 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Ancestor 4</td>
    <td>Ancestor 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ancestor 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Ancestor 5</td>
    <td>Ancestor 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ancestor 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Ancestor 3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Ancestor 6</td>
    <td>Ancestor 12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ancestor 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Ancestor 7</td>
    <td>Ancestor 14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ancestor 15</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>



What's the most efficient way to add/remove columns to the end of this pedigree table using javascript or jQuery? Each new column doubles the number of cells. I need to add/remove columns on the fly, and retain any data that is in the table. Thanks in advance for your help.

Use a modern framework like React to make this real easy

Potentially use [tag:datatables] which builds the HTML on top of data

You might like to consider not using tables for something that doesn't look like tabular data as all the work arounds for rowspan makes it substantially more complicated than it needs to be.

This is simply how I display pedigree data. This allows the data for each ancestor to vary, and the HTML table automatically adjusts to compensate.
I've experimented with other methods (divs, css, etc). It's very complicated handling varying lengths of data while still maintaining the correct structure of a pedigree tree.
How I store the data in the database looks completely different than what I am doing here. I have nearly a million dog pedigrees in my database that are automatically linked together by ancestry.
Thanks for your input.
